# Where should focus go if element disappears from the webpage

Tags: web, focus, accessibility, usability

I have an interesting question about focus in webpages. This relates mainly to the interplay of mouse and keyboard. Say I have an array of objects in the webpage in which one is "Focused" or selected, and there's a way to navigate them using tab. If the element has a delete button and I click on it, what should happen to the focus?

My theory is that the focus should disappear because the element that is acted on gains focus and subsequently disappears. This creates a weird situation in which the focus is then relegated to the root element, and tabbing subsequently goes to the top element in the page.

Would like to hear some opinions on this.

Comment: Yup, I did. If I have 4 elements and I delete the third one. The focus typically goes back to the root element, and tabbing starts from the first item. This is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/S2aab/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of objects, make it so that when the currently focused object disappears, the previous object becomes in focus. That seems the most user-friendly to me. I believe you can use JQuery to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Often in a list of elements, if you are focused on the Nth item, then remove the Nth item, the focus stays on the Nth item, as counted against the updated (shortened) list of items.

This is true for e.g. spreadsheet programs and email clients.

Comment: That's a good point. Let me go try out some spreadsheet/email clients.

Comment: I just did. It's interesting. For example: In Google Spreadsheets, the focus shifts to the next item. In Form edit view, there's a similar case in which they allow you to do say radio buttons, the delete moves the focus to the previous one. I guess there's no right answer huh.

Comment: @johncch All the spreadsheet and email programs I've tested behave in the way I've described.  However, it sounds like your case is slightly different from email/spreadsheet, and so you have a potential reason (and some potential prior art) for implementing it differently.  I guess the best path is to choose what you think will be most convenient for the most amount of your users.

Answer (score 0):

Without more context of what you are deleting and what other controls or headings are nearby, it is difficult to say what should gain focus. However, it should not be the root element as this is very disorientating. http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/usage